# Error logger and sasl reports show double on shell - how to see only the formatted version

Tags: shell, erlang, error-logging, sasl

When I start my application with the shell I see all error_logger reports twice.

One version is formatted like with `~p` and the there is the nicely formatted one:

```
{info_report,<0.48.0>,
             {<0.425.0>,std_info,
              [{chan,ser_200},
               usb_port,send,
               {data,"6d e1 00 00 00 04 00 00 06 8f"}]}}

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Apr-2011::16:43:24 ===
    chan: ser_200
    usb_port
    send
    data: "6d e1 00 00 00 04 00 00 06 8f"
```

How can I get rid of this redundant display?

To clarify, what I would like to see on the screen is only:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 8-Apr-2011::16:43:24 ===
    chan: ser_200
    usb_port
    send
    data: "6d e1 00 00 00 04 00 00 06 8f"
```

**I'm not asking about writing it to a file.**  This is alredy done with the `mf` logger.

What I want to improve is the live display on the screen.

I'm starting Erlang like this:

```
erl +W w -boot start_sasl -config myconfig ...
```

Application config file looks like this:

```
[{sasl, [
    {sasl_error_logger, tty},   
    {error_logger_mf_dir,"./log"},  
    {error_logger_mf_maxbytes,10485760}, % 10 MB
    {error_logger_mf_maxfiles, 10}]}].
```

Comment: How's your logging set up? Erlang doesn't do this by default.

Comment: @Adam: I think your inquiry made me find the problem ... just have to check.

Comment: @Adam: yeah it was as I thoght (see below) ... sometimes there is a need for the right questions to be asked. Thanks for asking :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it out:

There was a overlooked catch all clause in one of my own error handlers left over from ancient times in another project:

```
handle_event(Event, State) ->
    io:format("~p\n", [Event]),
```

This cause the `~p` like output ... because I'm using `~p`.

Once I removed the `io:format/2` call the double printing disappeared.